# How to add variable into path string in copy command PSQL

Tags: postgresql, psql

I'm using psql to run a .sql file to copy data from csv files into Postgres, but the folder contains csv files is changed everyday, so I want to add a variable into path code

This is my code

```
delete from table1;
delete from table2;
delete from table3;
\copy table1 FROM 'D:\tamlam\' + convert(date,getdate()) + '\file1.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER QUOTE '"' NULL '';
```

Comment: `convert()` and `getdate()` are invalid in Postgres to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `PROGRAM` option.

See [**this documentation**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203090/how-do-i-get-current-datetime-on-the-windows-command-line-in-a-suitable-format) how to get date in a desired format in Windows batch.

Put that in a script which does `TYPE %filenamevariable%` at the end. Let's say the script is named `data_gen`. You may then do

```
\COPY table1 FROM PROGRAM '\scriptpath\data_gen'
```

For Unix users, it is simpler, `date` command with options can generate date in a format and set a variable. then simply do `cat $filenamevariable` at the end of program